# JDBC driver escaping arguments for prepared statement?

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-injection

From the [OWASP page on *Preventing SQL Injection in Java*](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java#Prepared_Statements):

> Variables passed as arguments to prepared statements will automatically be escaped by the JDBC driver.

I understand how prepared statements seperate user input to be handled as parameter content and not as part of SQL command. But I stumbled across the quoted sentence above and I am wondering what’s all the escaping about. How does that help prevent the injection attack?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your statement is

```
"select * from foo where name = '" + name + "'";
```

Now if the name variable happens to be O'Reilly, you end up with the following SQL query, which is invalid:

```
select * from foo where name = 'O'Reilly'
```

Use a prepared statement instead:

```
"select * from foo where name = ?"
```

The driver will then bind the parameter correctly as a string, and the single quote in O'Reilly won't be interpreted as the end of the string started at `'O`.

In this simple case, not using a prepared statement will "only" lead to an exception in your app. But if someone uses a name like

```
' or 1 = 1 or name <> '
```

the query will become

```
select * from foo where name = '' or 1 = 1 or name <> ''
```

and the query will thus load every single row of the table. That's what SQL injection is all about.

Comment: It gets even better when my name is `' or 1=1;delete from foo where id>0;select * from foo where name='`

Comment: @vanOekel: but is there any database driver accepting to execute several statements at once?

Comment: Not if you use a prepared statement, but if you are lazy and use `connection.createStatement().execute(query)` the driver can allow multiple statements (I use it in unit tests to insert multiple records in one go).

Comment: Thank you, i understood what an sql injection is -  but was wondering why escaping prevents sql injection attacks, so i get it -it doesnt

Comment: It does. Because apostrophes are not interpreted as part of the query anymore. They're interpreted as part of the value of the argument of the query. In short, the prepared statement executes the following query instead: `select * from foo where name = 'O''Reilly'`. Try it by yourself, and see what happens.